# Which random number generator does Excel VBA use?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-365

Question in the title - I was looking to establish which random number generator VBA uses i.e., in Randomize and Rnd?  According to Microsoft's documentation Excel itself uses Mersenne Twister - which is apparently very good, but you can't seed. I can't seem to find an answer for VBA in the Microsoft documentation.

I'm using Excel 365 for this as I appreciate this is something which could change from version to version.

Comment: Not sure if this will answer your question, but take a look at http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/BASIC/basic.html and http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/BASIC/mt19937arVBcode.txt and http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/EXCEL/excel.html

Comment: Several questions about this, see this as one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38891165/4961700

Comment: Thanks for the response. I was able to get the VBA implementation of the MT there, and I'm happy to implement it, but I was more keen to understand the generator that VBA uses if I don't implement it :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only piece of information I could obtain about the current (i.e., Excel 365) random number generator used by Excel VBA is [Visual Basic for Applications/A PRNG for VBA (a wikibook)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/A_PRNG_for_VBA), which states "Microsoft's Visual Basic for Applications (VBA), at present uses a linear congruential generator (LCG) for pseudo-random number generation in the Rnd() function" and at the bottom "This page was last edited on 16 April 2020, at 06:55."
This alone would answer you question.

But since it is not necessarily an authoritative source, you would have to check this.
[Is Excel VBA's Rnd() really this bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891165/is-excel-vbas-rnd-really-this-bad) shows an example for how to do this.

As an alternative, [this](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/A_PRNG_for_VBA#Microsoft's_Rnd()_algorithm) shows the basic algorithm for Excel's `Rnd`:

```
x1 = ( x0 * a + c ) MOD m
Rnd() = x1/m
```

where:

```
Rnd() = returned value
m = modulus = (2^24)
x1 = new value
x0 = previous value (initial value 327680)
a = 1140671485
c = 12820163
Repeat length = m = (2^24) = 16,777,216
```

You may implement it and compare the results it produces with the results from `Rnd`, and check if it is faithful.

Note: You are right in that this changed across versions.
See, e.g., [How good is the RAND() function in Excel for Monte Carlo simulation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5886237/how-good-is-the-rand-function-in-excel-for-monte-carlo-simulation)
In particular, the update between 2007 ([On the accuracy of statistical procedures in Microsoft Excel 2007](http://www.pages.drexel.edu/~bdm25/excel2007.pdf)) and 2010 ([On the accuracy of statistical procedures in Microsoft Excel 2010](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266025083_On_the_Accuracy_of_Statistical_Procedures_in_Microsoft_Excel_2010)).
Perhaps there's a niche for yet another paper, as of now.

---

As for alternative generators, in case you don't like what is built-in, there are quite a few out there.
A brief list (some are posted in comments) is given here, code is posted below for clarity:

1. [Mersenne Twister in BASIC](http://www.math.sci.hiroshima-u.ac.jp/~m-mat/MT/VERSIONS/BASIC/basic.html)
2. [VBA Code - Wichmann-Hill (1982)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/A_PRNG_for_VBA#VBA_Code_-_Wichmann-Hill_(1982))
3. [Is Excel VBA's Rnd() really this bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38891165/is-excel-vbas-rnd-really-this-bad) (answers there)
4. [Mersenne Twister Random Number Generator Algorithm](https://www.montecarloexceladdin.com/mersenne-twister-pseudorandom-number-generator-algorithm)

---

**Code from links above**

1. Carmine Arturo Sangiovanni's implementation of Mersenne-Twister

```
' Visual Basic Mersenne-Twister
' Author: Carmine Arturo Sangiovanni
'         carmine @ daygo.com.br
'     daygo_gaming @ hotmail.com
'
'         Aug 13,2004
'
'         based on C++ code
'
'
'   Jan 4, 2010
'   rev1
'   bug fixes sent by Takano Akio (aljee @ hiper.cx)
'   look for 'rev1:' to see changes

Option Explicit

Const N = 624
Const M = 397

Global mt(0 To N) As Currency
Global mti As Currency

Dim MATRIX_A As Currency
Dim UPPER_MASK As Currency
Dim LOWER_MASK As Currency
Dim FULL_MASK As Currency
Dim TEMPERING_MASK_B As Currency
Dim TEMPERING_MASK_C As Currency

Function tempering_shift_u(ty As Currency)
    tempering_shift_u = f_and(Int(ty / 2048@), FULL_MASK)
End Function

Function tempering_shift_s(ty As Currency)
    tempering_shift_s = and_ffffffff(ty * 128@)
End Function

Function tempering_shift_t(ty As Currency)
    tempering_shift_t = and_ffffffff(ty * 32768@)
End Function

Function tempering_shift_l(ty As Currency)
    tempering_shift_l = f_and(Int(ty / 262144@), FULL_MASK)
End Function

Function f_and(p1 As Currency, p2 As Currency)
    Dim v As Currency
    Dim i As Integer

    If (p1 < UPPER_MASK) And (p2 < UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_and = p1 And p2
    End If

    If (p1 < UPPER_MASK) And (p2 >= UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_and = p1 And (p2 - UPPER_MASK)
    End If

    If (p1 >= UPPER_MASK) And (p2 < UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_and = (p1 - UPPER_MASK) And p2
    End If

    If (p1 >= UPPER_MASK) And (p2 >= UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_and = (p1 - UPPER_MASK) And (p2 - UPPER_MASK)
        f_and = f_and + UPPER_MASK
    End If
End Function

Function f_or(p1 As Currency, p2 As Currency)
    Dim v As Currency
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim f As Boolean

    If (p1 < UPPER_MASK) And (p2 < UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_or = p1 Or p2
    End If
    If (p1 < UPPER_MASK) And (p2 >= UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_or = p1 Or (p2 - UPPER_MASK)
        f_or = f_or + UPPER_MASK
    End If
    If (p1 >= UPPER_MASK) And (p2 < UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_or = (p1 - UPPER_MASK) Or p2          'rev1: replaced 'And' with 'Or'
        f_or = f_or + UPPER_MASK
    End If
    If (p1 >= UPPER_MASK) And (p2 >= UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_or = (p1 - UPPER_MASK) Or (p2 - UPPER_MASK)   'rev1: replaced 'And' with 'Or'
        f_or = f_or + UPPER_MASK
    End If
End Function

Function f_xor(p1 As Currency, p2 As Currency)
    Dim v As Currency
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim f1 As Boolean, f2 As Boolean

    If (p1 < UPPER_MASK) And (p2 < UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_xor = p1 Xor p2
    End If
    If (p1 < UPPER_MASK) And (p2 >= UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_xor = p1 Xor (p2 - UPPER_MASK)
        f_xor = f_xor + UPPER_MASK
    End If
    If (p1 >= UPPER_MASK) And (p2 < UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_xor = (p1 - UPPER_MASK) Xor p2
        f_xor = f_xor + UPPER_MASK
    End If
    If (p1 >= UPPER_MASK) And (p2 >= UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_xor = (p1 - UPPER_MASK) Xor (p2 - UPPER_MASK)
    End If
End Function

Function f_lower(ByVal p1 As Currency)          'rev1: added ByBal
    Do
        If p1 < UPPER_MASK Then
            f_lower = p1
            Exit Do
        Else
            p1 = p1 - UPPER_MASK
        End If
    Loop
End Function

Function f_upper(ByVal p1 As Currency)          'rev1: added ByVal
    If p1 > LOWER_MASK Then
        f_upper = UPPER_MASK
    Else
        f_upper = 0
    End If
End Function

Function f_xor3(p1 As Currency, p2 As Currency, p3 As Currency)
    Dim v As Currency
    Dim tmp As Currency
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim f As Integer


    If (p1 < UPPER_MASK) And (p2 < UPPER_MASK) Then
        tmp = p1 Xor p2
    End If
    If (p1 < UPPER_MASK) And (p2 >= UPPER_MASK) Then
        tmp = p1 Xor (p2 - UPPER_MASK)
        tmp = tmp + UPPER_MASK
    End If
    If (p1 >= UPPER_MASK) And (p2 < UPPER_MASK) Then
        tmp = (p1 - UPPER_MASK) Xor p2
        tmp = tmp + UPPER_MASK
    End If
    If (p1 >= UPPER_MASK) And (p2 >= UPPER_MASK) Then
        tmp = (p1 - UPPER_MASK) Xor (p2 - UPPER_MASK)
    End If

    If (tmp < UPPER_MASK) And (p3 < UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_xor3 = tmp Xor p3
    End If
    If (tmp < UPPER_MASK) And (p3 >= UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_xor3 = tmp Xor (p3 - UPPER_MASK)
        f_xor3 = f_xor3 + UPPER_MASK
    End If
    If (tmp >= UPPER_MASK) And (p3 < UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_xor3 = (tmp - UPPER_MASK) Xor p3
        f_xor3 = f_xor3 + UPPER_MASK
    End If
    If (tmp >= UPPER_MASK) And (p3 >= UPPER_MASK) Then
        f_xor3 = (tmp - UPPER_MASK) Xor (p3 - UPPER_MASK)
    End If
End Function

Function and_ffffffff(ByVal c As Currency)      'rev1: added ByVal
    Dim e As Currency
    Dim i As Integer

    i = 32
    Do
        e = 2 ^ (i + 16)
        Do While c >= e
            c = c - e
        Loop
        i = i - 1
    Loop While i > 15
    and_ffffffff = c
End Function

Sub random_init(seed As Currency)
    mt(0) = and_ffffffff(seed)
    For mti = 1 To N - 1
        mt(mti) = and_ffffffff(69069 * mt(mti - 1))
    Next mti
End Sub

Function Mersenne_twister_random(max As Integer)

    Dim kk As Integer

    Dim ty1 As Currency
    Dim ty2 As Currency
    Dim y As Currency

    Dim mag01(0 To 1) As Currency

    MATRIX_A = 2567483615@              '&H9908b0df
    UPPER_MASK = 2147483648@            '&H80000000
    LOWER_MASK = 2147483647@            '&H7fffffff
    FULL_MASK = LOWER_MASK + UPPER_MASK '&Hffffffff
    TEMPERING_MASK_B = 2636928640@      '&H9d2c5680
    TEMPERING_MASK_C = 4022730752@      '&Hefc60000

    mag01(0) = 0@
    mag01(1) = MATRIX_A

    If mti >= N Then
        If mti = N + 1 Then
            random_init 4537
        End If

        For kk = 0 To (N - M) - 1
            y = f_or(f_upper(mt(kk)), f_lower(mt(kk + 1)))
            mt(kk) = f_xor3(mt(kk + M), Int(y / 2@), mag01(f_and(y, 1)))
        Next kk

        For kk = kk To (N - 1) - 1
            y = f_or(f_upper(mt(kk)), f_lower(mt(kk + 1)))
            mt(kk) = f_xor3(mt(kk + (M - N)), Int(y / 2@), mag01(f_and(y, 1)))
        Next kk

        y = f_or(f_upper(mt(N - 1)), f_lower(mt(0)))
        mt(N - 1) = f_xor3(mt(M - 1), Int(y / 2@), mag01(f_and(y, 1)))
        mti = 0
    End If

    '---------------------------------------------------
    y = mt(mti): mti = mti + 1

    '---------------------------------------------------
    y = f_xor(y, tempering_shift_u(y))

    ty1 = f_and(tempering_shift_s(y), TEMPERING_MASK_B)
    y = f_xor(y, ty1)

    ty1 = f_and(tempering_shift_t(y), TEMPERING_MASK_C)
    y = f_xor(y, ty1)

    y = f_xor(y, tempering_shift_l(y))

    '---------------------------------------------------
    If max = 0 Then
        Mersenne_twister_random = 0
    Else
        Mersenne_twister_random = Int(y / 32) Mod max
    End If
End Function
```

2. Code here should be saved as a separate standard module in Excel.

```
Option Explicit
Dim nSamples As Long
Dim nX As Long, nY As Long, nZ As Long

Sub TestRndX()
    'run this to obtain RndX() samples
    'Wichmann, Brian; Hill, David (1982), Algorithm AS183:
    'An Efficient and Portable Pseudo-Random Number Generator,
    'Journal of the Royal Statistical Society. Series C
    Dim n As Long

    'reset module variables
    nX = 0: nY = 0: nZ = 0

    RandomizeX
    For n = 1 To 10
        Debug.Print RndX()
        MsgBox RndX()
    Next n

    'reset module variables
    nX = 0: nY = 0: nZ = 0

End Sub

Sub TestScatterChartOfPRNG()
    'run this to make a point scatter chart
    'using samples from RndX

    Dim vA As Variant, n As Long
    Dim nS As Long, nR As Double

    'remove any other charts
    'DeleteAllCharts

    'reset module variables
    nX = 0: nY = 0: nZ = 0

    'set number of samples here
    nSamples = 1000
    ReDim vA(1 To 2, 1 To nSamples) 'dimension array

    'load array with PRNG samples
    RandomizeX
    For n = 1 To nSamples
        nR = RndX()
        vA(1, n) = n  'x axis data - sample numbers
        vA(2, n) = nR 'y axis data - prng values
    Next n

    'make scatter point chart from array
    ChartScatterPoints vA, 1, 2, nSamples & " Samples of RndX()", _
                "Sample Numbers", "PRNG Values [0,1]"

    'reset module work variables
    nX = 0: nY = 0: nZ = 0

End Sub

Sub RandomizeX(Optional ByVal nSeed As Variant)
   'sets variables for PRNG procedure RndX()

   Const MaxLong As Double = 2 ^ 31 - 1
   Dim nS As Long
   Dim nN As Double

   'make multiplier
   If IsMissing(nSeed) Then
      nS = Timer * 60
   Else
      nN = Abs(Int(Val(nSeed)))
      If nN > MaxLong Then 'no overflow
         nN = nN - Int(nN / MaxLong) * MaxLong
      End If
      nS = nN
   End If

   'update variables
   nX = (nS Mod 30269)
   nY = (nS Mod 30307)
   nZ = (nS Mod 30323)

   'avoid zero state
   If nX = 0 Then nX = 171
   If nY = 0 Then nY = 172
   If nZ = 0 Then nZ = 170

End Sub

Function RndX(Optional ByVal nSeed As Long = 1) As Double
   'PRNG - gets pseudo random number - use with RandomizeX
   'Wichmann-Hill algorithm of 1982

   Dim nResult As Double

   'initialize variables
   If nX = 0 Then
      nX = 171
      nY = 172
      nZ = 170
   End If

   'first update variables
   If nSeed <> 0 Then
      If nSeed < 0 Then RandomizeX (nSeed)
      nX = (171 * nX) Mod 30269
      nY = (172 * nY) Mod 30307
      nZ = (170 * nZ) Mod 30323
   End If

   'use variables to calculate output
   nResult = nX / 30269# + nY / 30307# + nZ / 30323#
   RndX = nResult - Int(nResult)

End Function

Sub ChartScatterPoints(ByVal vA As Variant, RowX As Long, RowY As Long, _
                     Optional sTitle As String = "", Optional sXAxis As String, _
                     Optional sYAxis As String)

    'array input must contain two data rows for x and y data
    'parameters for user title, x axis and y axis labels
    'makes a simple point scatter chart

    Dim LBC As Long, UBC As Long, LBR As Long, UBR As Long, n As Long, bOptLim As Boolean
    Dim X As Variant, Y As Variant, sX As String, sY As String, sT As String, oC As Chart

    LBR = LBound(vA, 1): UBR = UBound(vA, 1)
    LBC = LBound(vA, 2): UBC = UBound(vA, 2)
    ReDim X(LBC To UBC)
    ReDim Y(LBC To UBC)

    'labels for specific charts
    If sTitle = "" Then sT = "Title Goes Here" Else sT = sTitle
    If sXAxis = "" Then sX = "X Axis Label Goes Here" Else sX = sXAxis
    If sYAxis = "" Then sY = "Y Axis Label Goes Here" Else sY = sYAxis

    If RowX < LBR Or RowX > UBR Or RowY < LBC Or RowY > UBC Then
        MsgBox "Parameter data rows out of range in ChartColumns - closing"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'transfer data to chart arrays
    For n = LBC To UBC
        X(n) = vA(RowX, n) 'x axis data
        Y(n) = vA(RowY, n) 'y axis data
    Next n

    'make chart
    Charts.Add

    'set chart type
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlXYScatter 'point scatter chart

    'remove unwanted series
    With ActiveChart
        Do Until .SeriesCollection.Count = 0
            .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
        Loop
    End With


    'assign the data and labels to a series
    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
        If .Count = 0 Then .NewSeries
            If Val(Application.Version) >= 12 Then
                .Item(1).Values = Y
                .Item(1).XValues = X
            Else
                .Item(1).Select
                Names.Add "_", X
                ExecuteExcel4Macro "series.x(!_)"
                Names.Add "_", Y
                ExecuteExcel4Macro "series.y(,!_)"
                Names("_").Delete
            End If
    End With

    'apply title string, x and y axis strings, and delete legend
    With ActiveChart
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = sT
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis) 'X
        .Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Text = sX
        .SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleRotated) 'Y
        .Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Text = sY
        .Legend.Delete
    End With

    'trim axes to suit
    With ActiveChart
    'X Axis
        .Axes(xlCategory).Select
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinimumScale = 0
        .Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = nSamples
        .Axes(xlCategory).MajorUnit = 500
        .Axes(xlCategory).MinorUnit = 100
        Selection.TickLabelPosition = xlLow

    'Y Axis
        .Axes(xlValue).Select
        .Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = -0.2
        .Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 1.2
        .Axes(xlValue).MajorUnit = 0.1
        .Axes(xlValue).MinorUnit = 0.05
    End With


    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Select

    Set oC = Nothing

End Sub

Sub DeleteAllCharts5()
    'run this to delete all ThisWorkbook charts

    Dim oC

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    For Each oC In ThisWorkbook.Charts
        oC.Delete
    Next oC

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

3. This is a SO link.
4. This is a workbook for downloading.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understood they didn't use anything particularly good - I'm surprised they don't just use the same RNG as what Excel uses! I'm currently using that VBA implementation of the Mersenne Twister from the Hiroshima University, it seems to work absolutely fine and gives me the randomness and cycle length needed for what I'm doing.

The SO quote you've left makes is look like the underlying VBA pRNG is *really* bad, I didn't know just how bad before. Thanks.

Comment: @NWhittle - A couple of comments: 1) The quote is not from SO. 2) I tried to answer the question: "Which random number generator does Excel VBA use?"
If you were more curious about "Why not using the same in Excel and Excel VBA?", I wouldn't know...

Comment: it's a good answer, and I think it's the correct one! 

I appreciate my comment might have been unclear -  when I said quote I was talking about the link to the SO article. Appreciate that literal quote in your response was from the wikibook.

Comment: I didn't set the bounty, so I don't believe I can award it - was set by someone else! I've accepted the answer as it answers the question I asked, but think the bounty is someone else's gift.

Comment: Link-only answers are generally [frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/204922) on Stack Overflow. In time it is possible for links to atrophy and become unavailable, meaning that your answer is useless to users in the future. It would be best if you could provide the general details of your answer in your actual post, citing your link as a reference.

Comment: @eirikdaude - I have updated the answer. As usual, I did not copy contents from SO links. Links to pdf papers are just that.
The general details of the answer to the specific question are given in the first  paragraph: "Microsoft's Visual Basic for Applications (VBA), at present uses a linear congruential generator (LCG) for pseudo-random number generation in the Rnd() function".
The following are forms of verifying this assertion (I did not implement them), and as an extra (as it is not part of the question) alternative algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

Should you require *truly random numbers*, study my project [VBA.Random](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Random).

Among other functions, matching different purposes, it also contains a direct substitute for `Rnd`:

```vb
' Returns a true random number as a Double, like Rnd returns a Single.
' The value will be less than 1 but greater than or equal to zero.
'
' Usage: Excactly like Rnd:
'
'   TrueRandomValue = RndQrn[(Number)]
'
'   Number < 0  ->  The same number every time, using Number as the seed.
'   Number > 0  ->  The next number in the pseudo-random sequence.
'   Number = 0  ->  The most recently generated number.
'   No Number   ->  The next number in the pseudo-random sequence.
'
' 2019-12-21. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function RndQrn( _
    Optional ByVal Number As Single = 1) _
    As Double
    
    Static Value            As Double
    
    Select Case Number
        Case Is > 0 Or (Number = 0 And Value = 0)
            ' Return the next number in the random sequence.
            Value = CDbl(QrnDecimal)
        Case Is = 0
            ' Return the most recently generated number.
        Case Is < 0
            ' Not supported by QRN.
            ' Retrieve value from RndDbl.
            Value = RndDbl(Number)
    End Select
    
    ' Return a value like:
    ' 0.171394365283966
    RndQrn = Value
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access Excel's RAND function from VBA - annoyingly, it isn't included in Application.WorksheetFunction, but there is a much faster way anyway, if you have Excel 365.

The code below uses the new RANDARRAY function to pull in 1000 random numbers from Excel, use them as needed, and pull in more as required. Retrieving many at a time greatly improves speed.

```
Function RandXLa() As Single
  Static Remaining As Long, R() As Variant
  If Remaining = 0 Then 'get more numbers if necessary
    R = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandArray(1000, 1)
    Remaining = 1000
  End If
  RandXLa = R(Remaining, 1)
  Remaining = Remaining - 1
End Function
```